# Get the Age format from the givent input param

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
DECLARE @AGE_NME VARCHAR(250),@OUTPUT Varchar(Max)

SET @AGE_NME='056YRS03MTHS13DAYS/M' --MY INPUT AGE FORMAT WILL BE LIKE THIS.


SET @OUTPUT= ??

--I WANT THE OUTPUT AS  BELOW

/*  IF MY @AGE_NME (INPUT) IS  

----YEAR PART CONDITIONS

'056Yrs03Mths13Days/Male' then @OUTPUT ='56Yrs03Mths13Days'

'056Yrs00Mths13Days/Male' then @OUTPUT = '56Yrs13Days/Male'

'056Yrs06Mths00Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '56Yrs06Mths/Male' 

'056Yrs00Mths20Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '56Yrs20Days/Male' 

'056Yrs00Mths00Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '56Yrs/Male' 

'000Yrs09Mths015Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '09Mths015Days/Male' 

----MONTH PART CONDITIONS

'000Yrs09Mths15Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '09Mths15Days/Male' 

'000Yrs09Mths00Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '09Mths/Male' 

----DAYS PART CONDITIONS

'000Yrs00Mths18Days/Male' then  @OUTPUT = '18Days/Male' 

*/
```

NOTE: Here I just want to simply say that my problem is whenever we pass "Years" (OR) "Month" (OR) "DAY" as zero (0) then it should not be shown in the output.

Comment: Please help me out from this ,whenever  "Years" (OR) "Month" (OR) "DAY" is passed Zero (0) then it should not be Shown in Output

Answer (score 1):

**Attention** Your attempt to declare the variable `@OUTPUT` must be wrong:

```
DECLARE @AGE_NME VARCHAR(250),@OUTPUT DATETIME
```

Your desired output-format is - for sure! - no `DATETIME`...

### Try this

This will first extract all parts out of your combined string and cast them as `INT`. The string is re-built using the int values after a check of `>0`

`REPLACE` AND `STR` are used to pad the numbers with zeros:

```
DECLARE @AGE_NME VARCHAR(250),@OUTPUT VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @AGE_NME='000YRS03MTHS00DAYS/MALE';

WITH AllParts AS 
(
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(@AGE_NME,3) AS INT) AS yrs
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@AGE_NME,7,2) AS INT) AS mths
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@AGE_NME,13,2) AS INT) AS [days]
          ,RIGHT(@AGE_NME,CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(@AGE_NME))-1) AS sex
)
SELECT @OUTPUT=
       CASE WHEN yrs>0 THEN CAST(yrs AS VARCHAR(3)) + 'Yrs' ELSE '' END
     + CASE WHEN mths>0 THEN REPLACE(STR(mths,2),' ','0') + 'Mths' ELSE '' END
     + CASE WHEN [days]>0 THEN REPLACE(STR([days],2),' ','0') + 'Days' ELSE '' END
     + '/' + sex
FROM AllParts;

SELECT @OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Sorry..for your code if i pass '056YRS03MTHS00DAYS/MALE' as input it shows me 056Yrs03Mths/MALE but i don't want 0 before 56 .i want like(56Yrs03Mths/MALE)

Comment: i sincerely accept your answer.and thanks for the help.but my required output is another

Comment: @shungo i saw your update..its exactly what i required..thank you very much

Comment: @Mahesh, hi I updated once again. Is this now the way you need it?

Comment: @Mahesh As you are new here please allow me one hint: It is very kind of you to say *Thank you*, but it would be even kinder, to tick the acceptance check below the answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself, you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!